# Is there an easy way to call parent super function from inner class?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code

```
class DrawingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private inner class ImageInfoObserver : Observer<ImageInfo> {
        override fun onChanged(imageInfo: ImageInfo?) {
            // Is there a way to perform DrawingActivity.super.finish() ?
            superFinish()
        }
    }

    fun superFinish() {
        super.finish()
    }
    
    override fun finish() {
        ...
        super.finish()
    }
```

Currently, I need to specially create `superFinish()` function, in order for inner class `ImageInfoObserver` to call `DrawingActivity.super.finish()`

I was wondering, is there an easier way to accomplish so, without having to create `superFinish()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it in the same way you access `DrawingActivity` - but instead of `this@DrawingActivity` you use `super@DrawingActivity` instead. So

```
super@DrawingActivity.finish()
```

would be like calling `super.finish()` from inside `DrawingActivity`. The [docs have an example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#calling-the-superclass-implementation) too.

Is there any reason you don't want to call `finish()` on the actual class though? (i.e. `this@DrawingActivity.finish()`) Why do you want to skip the `DrawingActivity`'s own `finish` code? If there's a good reason for it, it might be worth making the extra code in the overridden `finish()` function conditional on some state variable.

That way it's clear from reading the function when certain stuff happens and when it doesn't, and all the finish teardown logic is handled in one place.

Comment: Mmmm.  I can't help wondering what sort of design requires this ability, what sort of maintenance problems it's laying down, and whether it could be changed to avoid this.

Comment: Yeah I might not have been clear enough about that, but I think if there's code in ``finish`` that sometimes needs to run, and sometimes it doesn't, then you should handle that in ``finish`` itself. Other components shouldn't be reaching behind the activity to pull a different plug, that's a bad sign for the future!